# onChange doesn't fire in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component, where I render a list of unordered elements inline and every time there is change in the selection I am trying to update the value in the store

```
class EditMode extends Component {

  changeComps = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);

  };

  render() {

    let compOptions = this.props.compOptions.map((val, idx) => {
        return (
            <li key={idx} data-key={idx} style={{backgroundColor: this.props.compCheckedVal === idx ? '#30C1C6' : 'white'}}>
                <input type="radio" value={val}  />
                <label htmlFor="">{val === 'No Coverage' ? val.toUpperCase() : val}</label>
            </li>
        )
    });

    return (
        <div className='editDetails'>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col">
                    {this.props.compDeductTitle}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col">
                    <ul onChange={this.changeComps}>
                        {compOptions}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            ..........
          </div>)
   }
```

At moment I am not sure why the **onChange** event handler does not fire. I don't even see the event being printed out in the console. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It should be onClick I guess

Comment: @Think-Twice i tried the onClick but value prints out as "undefined"

Comment: your op was about onchange isn't triggering right?

Comment: ok tell me WHAT VALUE ARE YOU TRYING TO GET?

Comment: Typically onChange is applied to form elements, not so sure this is going to work as I've never seen onChange applied to an unordered list.

Comment: As @Aaron said, `onChange` is usually used for form elements like text fields. It's not just a general 'something changed in some way' catch all handler. Your approach doesn't really make sense. You said you want to fire it when the selection changes, why don't you handle the action in the selection changing code? State/store changes shouldn't really be triggered by other store/state changes. Also, be aware that you're using array index as a key to elements. That is going to cause issues if your list is dynamic, React won't be able to properly update changes to the list.

Comment: what's value. I think you shouldn't use onChange for ul element

Answer (score 1):

`onChange` event will not work with `ul` element.

Please check here in [`more details`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change).

`compOptions`  can written in this way,if you want to attach `onChange` event.

```
let compOptions = this.props.compOptions.map((val, idx) => {
    return (
        <li key={idx} data-key={idx} style={{backgroundColor: this.props.compCheckedVal === idx ? '#30C1C6' : 'white'}}>
            <input type="radio" value={val} onChange={this.changeComps}  /> //attach onChange here directly
            <label htmlFor="">{val === 'No Coverage' ? val.toUpperCase() : val}</label>
        </li>
    )
});
```